# Panel plot with r

Tags: r

I have a csv file with 10 columns and want to read and plot 7 of them along with text file time series. With following code, I am able to draw them but facing few issues:

1] white space between plots is making each plot look very small. How to use most of space?
2] Legend is overlayed 7th plot. How to place it to the panel plot area of 8 and 9 (since not using panel plot areas 8 and 9)

3] How to make a common x and y axis and define individual title of each panel plot

```
library(qmap)
obs <- read.table("D:/test.txt")
mod <- read.csv("D:/pr.csv", header = FALSE)
par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma = c(4, 1, 1, 1))
for(i in 4:10){
modp <- mod[,i]
qm1.fit <- fitQmap(obs,modp,
                 method="PTF",
                 transfun="expasympt",
                 cost="RSS",wett.day=TRUE)
qm1 <- doQmap(modprecip,qm1.fit)

# repeated same procedure for qm2, qm3, qm4, and qm5

# QQ-plot of all mappings
obs_v <- as.vector(as.matrix(obs))
mod_v <- as.vector(as.matrix(modp))
qqplot(mod_v, obs_v, col = 1, xlab = 'Pm [mm/day]', ylab = 'Po [mm/day]')
qqline(qm1, col = 2, lwd = 2)
qqline(qm2, col = 3, lwd = 2)
qqline(qm3, col = 4, lwd = 2)
qqline(qm5, col = 5, lwd = 2)

}

legend("bottom", inset=c(-0.2,0), legend=c("A","B"), pch=c(1,3), title="Group")
```

Any help will be highly appreciative

[image]

Comment: There is no data or figure of the result. What are we suppose to do?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik added figure

Comment: This can easily be solved using [`ggplot2::facet_wrap`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of plots can very easily be generated using `ggplot2`. I'll show the following example from the `ggplot2` documentation as your question does not contain a repeatable example:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
d + facet_wrap(~ color)
```

[image]

`ggplot2` addresses your issues:

1. White space is no longer an issue.
2. legend is put nicely to the side.
3. by default the x and y axes are the same (you can turn this off if needed)

Also see [this tutorial](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_ggplot2.html) I wrote about `ggplot2` if you want to get up to speed with how `ggplot2` works.

Comment: so I need to write a data frame as an output of for loop and use it in ggplot2, right?

Comment: Correct, although I would use an `apply` style loop myself (e.g. `lapply`). See also [this link](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_control_flow.html).

Comment: `lapply` is very fast to give data frame but how do I use each column in that data frame one at a time and process it along with a separate time series. Little struggling....

Comment: That description is a bit vague. I think the best approach here is to open a new question. Do include a reproducible example.

Comment: In addition, if my question solves your issue you can click on the check mark just below my score indicator. This gives me some rep and signals to others that this question has been answered.

Comment: i think these comments illustrate the problem of "Q: I am using this--I have these specific questions about it" "A: here let me ignore your questions, you should use this other thing instead" "hey wait now i have even more questions and you didn't address any of the ones I asked in the first place." which seems to be the way SO is going lately. Then others who have the same question and are linked here will also not be helped

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I am still struggling with your proposed solution because use of `ggplot` requires x and y but in my for loop I am plotting `qqline` which requires only one numeric vector. I ended up with more questions than original questions I posted here on SO

Comment: Just create a dummy variable that is `1:length(y)`, where `y` is the vector to plot.

Comment: @rawr my answer using ggplot2 covers all of his questions. Making that kind of plot using base graphics would be a lot of work and require massive research from my side. This solves this issue in very minimal code. I don't see why this is not a legitimate answer.